# Setting message for user-defined exception in Django

Tags: django, exception

Currently I have the following code:

Definition of my self-defined exception class:

```
class BusinessLogicError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.value = message
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.message)
```

View code snippet (simplified)

```
try:
   raise BusinessLogicError('This is my error message')
except BusinessLogicError, e:
   print str(e)
```

The problem is that this code works without errors, but I get empty string printed to the console when `print str(e)` is executed. Instead, I would anticipate it to render `This is my error message`. What am I doing wrong ? Is the mistake in exception class definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used different attribute names in each method. You should make them consistent; use either `self.value` or `self.message`.

Comment: Daniel, a bit off-topic. Is there any widely accepted method to include the error code in the error defintion as well ?

Comment: Error status, I mean (400, 500, etc...)